# Shell script to name videos on device

Tags: linux, shell, usb, automount

I have a .sh script that automounts any usb device that is plugged in. I need it to also find if there are videos in a certain location on the device that is plugged in then write them to a videos.txt file. Here's what I have and its not working. Also I need it to put the mountpoint in the videos.txt file. ${MOUNTPOINT}$count is the path to the mounted device.

```
VIDEOS=ls ${MOUNTPOINT}$count/dcim/100Video | grep mp4
if [ "$VIDEOS" -ne "" ] ; then
    "${MOUNTPOINT}$count" > ${MOUNTPOINT}$count/videos.txt;
    "$VIDEOS" >> ${MOUNTPOINT}$count/videos.txt;
fi
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VIDEOS=$(ls ${MOUNTPOINT}$count/dcim/100Video | grep mp4)
if [ -n "$VIDEOS" ] ; then
    echo "${MOUNTPOINT}$count" > ${MOUNTPOINT}$count/videos.txt;
    echo "$VIDEOS" >> ${MOUNTPOINT}$count/videos.txt;
fi
```

use `$()` to execute process and return a value. use `-n` test to check for non-zero strings. `-ne` is used to check for numbers. `$VIDEOS` by itself is a string, not a command. in order to put a value into a file, you should `echo` it.

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm. Thanks for the help!